# Postfix is sending and receiving mail locally, but not to external mailbox

Tags: email, configuration, postfix

I have a CentOS box running my Apache website and Postfix, but whenever I try PHP's mail() function to my @aevidi email, it sends to my local mailbox in ~/mail, but is not visible in Zoho's webmail. When I send an email from my Gmail account to my @aevidi email, I see it in Zoho but not in my local mailbox (expected result). Here is my setup:

- Zoho as my email host for my custom domain
- CentOS box with my site and mail server (postfix)

[I followed this tutorial for my Zoho/SES/Postfix high level setup](http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2013/07/send-email-with-amazon-ses-postfix-zoho.html) (honestly not sure where SES comes into play)

[I followed this tutorial to setup Postfix](http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-mail-server-in-centos-6/) (and Dovecot before I realized what it did, but have removed it since).

---

`/var/log/maillog after executing mail()`

```
Aug  3 20:05:37 aevidi postfix/pickup[7702]: 31ADD40BDD: uid=48 from=<michael@chtoen.com>
Aug  3 20:05:37 aevidi postfix/cleanup[7707]: 31ADD40BDD: message-id=<20140804000537.31ADD40BDD@aevidi>
Aug  3 20:05:37 aevidi postfix/qmgr[7703]: 31ADD40BDD: from=<xxx@aevidi.com>, size=344, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  3 20:05:37 aevidi postfix/local[7709]: 31ADD40BDD: to=<xxx@aevidi.com>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.0
1/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Aug  3 20:05:37 aevidi postfix/qmgr[7703]: 31ADD40BDD: removed
```

---

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
myhostname = aevidi #This is my FQDN when I type 'hostname -f'
mydomain = aevidi.com
myorigin = $mydomain
home_mailbox = mail/
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

relayhost = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:25
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

---

`DNS configuration`

[image: Cloudflare DNS]

---

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by `@aevidi` email? You mean `aevidi.com`? If your postfix want to deliver mails for `aevidi.com`  to `Zoho` mail servers, then you should remove `$domain` from `mydestination`. That way postfix will consider `aevidi.com` as remote domain and deliver mails doing an `MX` lookup.

Comment: You are awesome! That was the fix. If you post it as the answer I will mark it correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `postfix` to deliver mails for `aevidi.com` by doing an `MX` lookup (`i.e` to Zoho mail servers, in your case), then you should remove `$domain` i.e `aevidi.com` from `mydestination`.